# page scrolls down when clicking href=#SomeDivName

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap topbar.

When I click on some navigation href

`href=#SomeDivName`

Like when you press the navigation in this page:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html#contact

The page scrolls down a bit.

I want the relevant section will appear after clicking,
but I don't want the page to scroll down.

Comment: `haref=#SomeDiveName`? do you mean `<a href="#SomeDiveName">`? I'm not familiar with the bootstrapper topbar so I may be missing something - but your questions is very unclear with no real detail. Please try to provide more information. What SHOULD the page do? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a[href="#SomeDiveName"]').on('click', false);
```

This will return false when you click on the anchor tag with an href attribute set to `#SomeDiveName`. Which will prevent the default behavior of the element, which in this case is to scroll to the element to which the href attribute refers.

If you have a set of these links then I'd suggest adding a class to identify them so you can select them all at once:

```
$('.stop-this-link').on('click', false);
```

This will prevent the default behavior for all elements with the `stop-this-link` class whenever the element is clicked. Selecting by class is a lot faster than by attribute too. When searching by attribute, every element in the DOM must be checked.

Note that returning `false` in a jQuery event handler is the same as calling: `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

For more info about these functions see here:

- `event.preventDefault()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault
- `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation

Comment: Can you just pass `false` to `.on` like that?  Shouldn't it be `.on('click', function(){return false;});`?

Comment: I can't remember who, but someone on SO showed me that about a week ago. `function(){ return false' }` does what? It returns `false`. Well `false` also returns `false` :). Kinda cool how it simplifies the code if all you want to do is prevent the default behavior or event bubbling.

Comment: But `function(){ return false' }` is a `function` where as `false` is a `boolean`.  I guess jQuery is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: But the end result of `function(){ return false' }` is just `false`. So jQuery only receives `false` in either case.

Comment: @Rocket: it has to do with JS's duck-typing. There's really no such thing as a function *type*, it's just a variable like anything else.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: There is a `function` type.  I mean, you can't call `false` like a function.  `typeof false` is `'boolean'` and, `typeof function(){return false;}` is `'function'`.

Comment: @Jasper: No, jQuery receives a function when you pass one, and false when you pass that.  The function is ran as a callback, not when it's passed. so `function(){ return false' }` and `false` are different.

Comment: @Jasper and @ChrisPratt: It's because jQuery checks explicitly for `false`, and replaces it with a function.  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L903

Comment: @Jasper added an example related to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html#contact

Comment: @EladBenda What should I do to reproduce your problem? Nothing happens with I click any link.

Comment: @Jasper, I have tried to give my code, but it's all broken http://jsfiddle.net/5BMr8/6/

Comment: @EladBenda I fixed a few errors but you have to link to your CSS and JS files, at the moment you are linking to: `Css/browser.css` and not `http://www.my-site.com/Css/browser.css`. That's just one example, all the relative paths have to be updated (shouldn't take you much time): http://jsfiddle.net/5BMr8/7/

Comment: @Rocket thanks for looking up the jQuery source. That's good information.

Comment: @Jasper where can I upload my files so I can set thier url in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jasper - yet in general - where can I host my js and css easily?

Comment: I'm not sure... I generally work online. You can get a free account with GitHub to host your code I believe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7549/discussion-between-elad-benda-and-jasper)

Comment: @Jasper, anyway you can see in my markup the #files section? i don't get it- why moving to this section cause scroll down?

Answer (score 4):

instead of using `<a href="#target">` use `<a data-target="#target">` and remove the href attribute

Comment: This didn't work at my end. Will like to know if there's any other change that I'll have to do in order to get the required functionality

Answer (score 1):

Jasper's answer is correct, however you might get some weirdness if you bind other things later. I tend to use this:

```
 $('.stop-this-link').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault() });
```

Essentially the same thing, but importantly it does not stop propagation of the event up the DOM, at the cost of being slightly more verbose.